# React-bootstrap Container acting wierd

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

Lately, I have been experimenting with the react-bootstrap Container component and I have stumbled over a small problem. When I render a webpage normally, set it at 400px, and inspect it, I have no padding or margin set, but when I inspect it thru a toggled device with width of 400px, my margin becomes 130px. Can someone tell me why that is and how could I make the margin disappear on small screens, no matter if the device toggler is used or not? Thank you!

[image: Without device toggler]

[image: With device toggler]